# Silex Doctrine Extensions

Tags: doctrine, silex

To make use of the Doctrine Extension in the Silex [usage documentation](http://silex.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extensions/doctrine.html?highlight=doctrine) they are asking that you

"Make sure you place a copy of Doctrine DBAL in vendor/doctrine-dbal and Doctrine Common in vendor/doctrine-common."

They then go onto an example of how to register with:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Extension\DoctrineExtension(), array(
    'db.options'            => array(
        'driver'    => 'pdo_sqlite',
        'path'      => __DIR__.'/app.db',
    ),
    'db.dbal.class_path'    => __DIR__.'/vendor/doctrine-dbal/lib',
    'db.common.class_path'  => __DIR__.'/vendor/doctrine-common/lib',
));
```

What I don't get are two things...

> 1) the path __DIR_.'vendor/doctrine-dbal/lib'

What does lib mean??  I don't see a lib folder or file in the doctrine package.

> 2) doctrine dbal and doctrine common...

The folder structure of the unpacked tar look like this:
[image]
does that mean I put the *contents* of each of those folders in their respective folders?

Thanks for your help.  I'm having more trouble figuring out paths to these extensions than I am the extensions themselves.

-J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lib` should correspond to the `DBAL/lib` folder and likewise with the `Common/lib` folder. I think these instructions are more inline with a [`composer`](http://packagist.org/) based installation layout.

Comment: I seemed to have figured it out... I had to copy the structure off of github rather than download the files from doctrine dbal...

Comment: Yeah, it's based on the GitHub repository. I wasn't aware of the fact that the package does not include it.

Answer (score 1):

Include them as submodules if you are using git as version control system (which you should).

Then just add them this way:

```
git submodule add git://github.com/doctrine/dbal.git vendor/doctrine-dbal
git submodule add git://github.com/doctrine/common.git vendor/doctrine-common
```

Next init the submodule folders:

```
git submodule init
```

and fetch them from git:

```
git submodule update --recursive
```

Answer (score 0):

After downloading the DBLA, copy the 'Doctrine' folder to 'vendor', then update db.dbal.class_path and db.common.class_path to '/vendor/'.

```
    $app->register(new Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider(), array(
        'db.options' => array(
            'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'dbname' => 'testdb',
            'user' => 'root',
            'password' => ''
        ),
        'db.dbal.class_path'    => __DIR__.'/vendor/',
        'db.common.class_path'  => __DIR__.'/vendor/',
    ));
```

or

Create the following folder structure in 'vendor'
'doctrine-dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/'
'doctrine-common/lib/Doctrine/Common/'

copy 'Doctrine/DBAL/' to 'vendor/doctrine-dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/'
copy 'Doctrine/Common/' to 'vendor/doctrine-common/lib/Doctrine/Common/'

```
    $app->register(new Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider(), array(
        'db.options'            => array(
            'driver'    => 'pdo_sqlite',
            'path'      => __DIR__.'/app.db',
        ),
        'db.dbal.class_path'    => __DIR__.'/vendor/doctrine-dbal/lib',
        'db.common.class_path'  => __DIR__.'/vendor/doctrine-common/lib',
    ));
```